# Creating an online questionnaire form - by Importing the questions from a spreadsheet?

Tags: plugins, import, google-docs, forms

I've got a spreadsheet where each row of the first column is a question, and the next 4 columns are the optional 4 answers to that question.

I want to turn these questions into an online form (like as the one offered by google docs)

Is there a form plugin (or another solution) that can offer something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option for a form plugin is [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/category/features/). It has the ability to create multiple choice options via a drop down or check box and you can use conditional logic that will display fields based on choices in previous fields.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Very interesting!  I see they have an import option. Sadly, it is not free...

Comment: oh gravity forms is free software. it just costs some money or some efforts to find someone who gives it to you.

Comment: +1 for Gravity Forms plugin. It's very useful and worth paying for the developer license if you are going to use it on multiple client sites,

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the google docs form with an iframe. Is that an option?

Comment: I can integrate the google doc form.  The problem is that the google form wizard can not import questions.

Comment: I would look inside google docs for such a functionality. This site might help: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Hakre, thank you.

I had a look at it, I don't think it is possible.  (I also dropped the question there)

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with Google forms is that adding a custom redirection page (thank you page, precisely), is a pain in the neck. Style can be changed with a little bit of workaround... And guess what, the Google form/thank you page has link for google docs, and if clicked on them, the links open up in the same iFrame, right on your page! So, i'd say go for some plugin, or some service like SurveyMonkey etc...
Let me know what solution you've found cause I'm looking for one too...

Regards,
Rutwick (WP developer, India)